# How to loop through an array and get how many zeros there are

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, rows

I have a 2D array and it's like a maze. 
So I loop through the first row to see if there is a zero (This zero is the opening) and then I go down to see if there is another zero below that zero.

The problem is that after the first 2 rows I don't know how I can write code to check left,right or down of that zero and move there and continue until I cannot do so any longer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AssignmentTwo
{   
   //int[rows][columns]
    int[][] gasCavern =  {{1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
                          {1,0,0,1,1,0,1},
                          {1,1,1,0,0,0,1},
                          {1,1,0,0,1,1,1},
                          {1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
                          {1,0,1,0,0,0,1},
                          {0,0,0,1,1,1,0},
                          {1,1,1,0,0,0,1}};

    int counter = 0;
    boolean checked = false;

    // forLoop that deals with the first 2 rows.
    // First check 1st row for a zero.
    // Then check down and increment counter which ultimately shows area.
    for(int column = 0; column < gasCavern[0].length; column++)
    {
       //Checking for opening in 1st row
       if(gasCavern[0][column]== 0)
      {
          counter++;
          gasCavern[0][column] = 2;

          if(gasCavern[1][column]==0)
          {
              counter++;
          }
      }
  }


      for(int i=1; i<gasCavern.length; i++)
      {
          for(int j=0; j < gasCavern.length; j++)
          {
              if(gasCavern[i][j])
              {
                  //Looking left
                  if(gasCavern[i][j-1]==2)
                  {                         
                    gasCavern[i][j-1]=2;
                    counter++;
                  }
                  //Looking Right
                  if(gasCavern[i][j+1]==2)
                  {
                      gasCavern[i][j+1]=2;
                      counter++;
                  }
                  //Looking up
                  if(gasCavern[i+1][j]==2)
                  {
                      gasCavern[i+1][j]=2;
                      counter++;
                  }
                  //Looking down
                  if(gasCavern[i-1][j]==2)
                  {
                      gasCavern[i-1][j]==2
                      counter++;
                  }
              }
         }
     }

public boolean checkedForZeros()
{
    //If returning false,go through while loop again
}
```

}

This is the code I have so far. In case I wasn't clear this is what I want to happen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOTyN.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I think with a bit more thought you would have got it!

Think about it, all you have to do is check the adjacent elements in the row you are looking at, which are just the columns in each side. Therefore:

```
[column+1]
```

Would check the element to the right, and:

```
[column-1]
```

Would check the element to the left.

Just be sure you don't accidentally go out of bounds.

EDIT: Let us know how you get on, if you are still struggling, I will provide more code, but try first.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my code to what I have now. I am at the stage where I change all the zeros I visited to 2's so I don't count them again. However I am unclear on how to continue from this point on. My professor suggested I use a while loop to enclose my 2 forLoops with the condition but still I am unsure.

Comment: @Anonymous are you still stuck with this?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
for (int x = 0; x < gasCavern.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < gasCavern[x].length; y++) {
        int num = gasCavern[x][y];
        if (num == 0) {
            // if it is a zero
        } else {
            // if it's not a zero (a one)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would check for all cases of '0'. He needs to track a path, i.e. if a '0' is adjacent to another '0'.

Comment: Seems similar to what I edited above. Still having a bit of a problem though